# SQL: Interpretation of multiple inner joins with brackets generated by Cognos

Tags: sql, teradata, cognos

One of my colleagues build a query in Cognos and generated a massive SQL query. Unfortunately, the query is super slow and I want to speed it up. The query includes multiple inner joins that have been connected with brackets. I suspect that the joins make to query slow and want to understand the logic behind those joins.

For me it seems like the brackets are unnecessary, but when I delete them I get a different result and the query is somehow slower.

```
SELECT "PO_SO_SchedLnVndrCnfrmn_v"."PO_DistribMthdCd" "C0",
       "LnPlnPlnt_Rptg_v"."RgnProdtReplenInd" "C1",
       "PlngProdt_Rptg_v"."GlblGndrDesc" "C2",
       "LnPlnPlnt_Rptg_v"."RgnLnchDesc" "C3" .....
FROM ((((("PLN"."PO_SO_SchedLnVndrCnfrmn_v" "PO_SO_SchedLnVndrCnfrmn_v"
          INNER JOIN "PLN"."Cust_Rptg_v" "Cust_Rptg_v" ON "PO_SO_SchedLnVndrCnfrmn_v"."SO_SoldToNbr" = "Cust_Rptg_v"."CustCd")
         INNER JOIN "PLN"."Div_v" "Div_v" ON "PO_SO_SchedLnVndrCnfrmn_v"."DivCd" = "Div_v"."DivCd")
        INNER JOIN "PLN"."Plnt_wExtndAttrs_v" "Plnt_wExtndAttrs_v" ON PO_SO_SchedLnVndrCnfrmn_v"."PlntCd" = "Plnt_wExtndAttrs_v"."PlntIdCd") 
INNER JOIN "PLN"."GAC_Rsn_v" "GAC_Rsn_v" on "PO_SO_SchedLnVndrCnfrmn_v"."GAC_RsnCd" = "GAC_Rsn_v"."GAC_RsnCd") 
INNER JOIN "PLN"."LnPlnPlnt_Rptg_v" "LnPlnPlnt_Rptg_v" on "PO_SO_SchedLnVndrCnfrmn_v"."PlntCd" = "LnPlnPlnt_Rptg_v"."PlntIdCd" and "PO_SO_SchedLnVndrCnfrmn_v"."ProdtCd" = "LnPlnPlnt_Rptg_v"."PlngProdtCd") where .....
GROUP BY .....
```

Comment: You're right, the brackets make no difference. Are you sure about the different results? As long as all are Inner Joins there should be no difference. Is this running on Teradata or MySQL? If it's Teradata can you post Explain?

Comment: I found out why it makes a difference. I used SAMPLE 10 which apparently doesn't give the top 10 results, but a random selection of results. I used the Teradata SQL Assistant
 However the query still takes a long time. Do you have any tips how I can speed the query up? I suspect the joins are the most time consuming thing?

Comment: The EXPLAIN is about 1000 lines long, so I won't post it for now. But thanks for pointing this out. I didn't know this command exists

Comment: One thing you can try to troubleshoot is to cut out the `JOINs` one at a time and re-run the query to see if one of them is causing the slow-down.  It wouldn't hurt to post the `EXPLAIN` either as an attachment if possible.

Comment: SAMPLE (and TOP) are applied *after* the full result set has been created (last step in Explain), thus it's not speeding up a query (only for a SELECT without WHERE/JOIN).

Comment: The parts of the query you posted look really simple.  There's nothing strange in the joins.  Removing the parentheses will have no effect.  But you didn't post the whole thing.  The query is probably slow because of a calculated item in the SELECT clause or some problem in the WHERE clause.  Are there sufficient filters?  Do the filters take advantage of database partitioning?

Comment: @dougp: The query looks simple, but those object names containing `_v` probably indicate *views* and those views are probably quite complex based on the *EXPLAIN is about 1000 lines long* remark :-)

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer

- Identify the fact table
- Check the filters over the fact table
- look at the database relations/indexes/evi's for the fact table
  You may have to create index/evi

At a glance, this looks like most of the tables are for descriptions

- Cust_Rptg_v is just description for customers
- Div_v for divisions
- Plnt_wExtndAttrs_v maybe is locations?
- GAC_Rsn_v for reason
- LnPlnPlnt_Rptg_v not sure..

What are the filters on PO_SO_SchedLnVndrCnfrmn_v?